# Simple and fast async binary TCP socket server?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I'm looking for a simple and fast TCP socket server written in C#. It should be async (run alongside a WinForms app) and support async receiving/sending data to connected clients. I found the following libraries that might work, but I'm looking for advice on specific libraries.

I'm trying to send binary data (using my custom serializer) from C# to an AS3 frontend. I have the client socket already written in AS3 but I need a reliable socket server in C#.

- [XYNetSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/xynetsocket.aspx) - single file, unreliable and misses packets, does not support binary
- [NetSockets](http://netsockets.codeplex.com/)
- [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)
- [SuperSocket](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/) - looks very bloated (100+ classes)

Which socket server library have you used with success? Does it support binary and is it reliable?

Comment: without knowing what you want to do, this is hard to answer. Basically, `Socket` provides everything you've said... and the [async IO API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) is the preferred one ; but you haven't given enough information to act as a comparator here. Yes, `Socket` supports binary (indeed: *only* binary), and yes: `Socket` is reliable... or at least, as reliable as network comms get.

Comment: How about my library: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people might tell you to create everything from scratch yourself, which I don't really understand as, like you say, its WAY faster and easier to use a library.

Using networkComms.net, assuming you would send your binary data as byte[], Simple client server example - [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/). WPF chat example - [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/). In both examples instead of sending and receiving strings you replace relevant sections with byte[]. 'Relevant' should be apparent based on the examples and included comments.

I have to add that I'm a developer for this library.

Comment: What is the minimum I need to use? Because I frequently modify everything and the smaller the library is the easier to understand and therefore update it is. Is the `NetworkCommensDotNet` subfolder inside the source ZIP enough? Or do I need all those DPS and encryption and compressor classes as well?

Comment: If you want the bare minimum I would recommend just using the core DLL, rather than worrying about the source download. That contains the minimum required for the library to function. If there are any features you think are missing we do our best to add anything on request.

Comment: Anyways, how do I maintain an active server instance, and which method do I call to send data to all clients on demand? (async)

Comment: The core DLL contains three projects, DPSBase (Serialisation), NetworkCommsDotNet (Sending) and the LZMA compressor (Compression), further project summaries found here http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/. All of the things to you need should be covered in the two examples I've linked.

Comment: But If I'm sending binary why do I need serialization or compression?

Comment: The serialization and compression features are completely optional. See the AdvancedSend example in the source download which demonstrates how to perform send/receive without using them. They are included in the core because they are used by default during connection handshakes etc.

Comment: Does NetworkComms support .Net Core?

Comment: @roozbehS - I don't think we created a compile config for .net core, so you might have to do a little rearranging to make it work.

Comment: @MarcF I'm having hard time to make it work with my .net core 2.2 , can you please lead me to a tutorial or instruction that can help?